# Firebase add another data to a child without overwriting existing data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this following method which i use when saving a new data

```
public void registerNewUser(FirebaseUser id,
                       String name,
                       String email,
                       int count) {

    User user = new User(name, email, count);

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference();
    ref.child("path")
            .child(id.getUid()).setValue(user);
}
```

I like to add a new data in the same child/folder when the user is done registering, this is what i have done so far.

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference();
    ref.child("path")
            .child(id.getUid()).setValue("THE NEW DATA");
```

But the problem is it clears and overwrite the old data. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference();
ref.child("path")
        .child(id.getUid()+"/username").setValue(user);
ref.child("path")
        .child(id.getUid()+"/newdata").setValue("THE NEW DATA");
```

> **Below Image Output Code**

```
ref.child("path")
    .child(id.getUid()+"/username").setValue(["username": "isabellap"]);
ref.child("path")
    .child(id.getUid()+"/build").setValue(["build": "1.0.7"]);
```

> **Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i want it to joined the existing save data not just create a new child